# Multiple Instances for TextToSpeech

Tags: android

I need to speak multiple language. I created an array for TextToSpeech.

```
private TextToSpeech[]              mTextSpeechs_;
mTextSpeechs_           = new TextToSpeech[5];
    mTextSpeechs_[0] = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) 
        {
            mTextSpeechs_[0].setLanguage(Locale.CHINESE);
            mTextSpeechs_[0].speak(getString(R.string.string_main_chineseready), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,"Display");
        }           
    });
    mTextSpeechs_[1] = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) 
        {
            mTextSpeechs_[1].setLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag("yue-HK"));
            mTextSpeechs_[1].speak(getString(R.string.string_main_hongkong), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,"Display");
        }           
    });
    mTextSpeechs_[2] = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) 
        {
            mTextSpeechs_[2].setLanguage(Locale.JAPAN);
            mTextSpeechs_[2].speak(getString(R.string.string_main_japan), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,"Display");
        }           
    });
    mTextSpeechs_[3] = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) 
        {
            mTextSpeechs_[3].setLanguage(Locale.KOREA);
            mTextSpeechs_[3].speak(getString(R.string.string_main_korea), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,"Display");
        }           
    });
    mTextSpeechs_[4] = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) 
        {
            mTextSpeechs_[4].setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
            mTextSpeechs_[4].speak(getString(R.string.string_main_english), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,"Display");
        }           
    });
....
//type 0 flush
//type 1 add
public void speakMultiLanguage(String text, int type,int langidx)
{       
    if( type == 0 )
        mTextSpeechs_[langidx_].speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,"Display");
    else if( type == 1)
        mTextSpeechs_[langidx_].speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null,"Display");
}
```

Now, When I call speakMultiLanguage function to speak specified language, it will delay about 5 seconds to speak. If the last language is same, it will not delay. Does anyone give me a solution to solve the delay?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't testing your particular case of multiple usage of TTS in array. But for me it looks none productive, especially memory and resources using.
In my case I initialise only one TTS object in `onCreate()` method of My Activity. And when I need to change languge to another, I'll use `tts.setLanguge(Locale)`.
In my case and with my virtual device this solution working immediately. 
initialise:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG, "TTS fault");
                }
            }
        });
        //....
    }
```

Change:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void prepareTTS(Locale newLocale){
        if (!tts.getVoice().getLocale().getISO3Language().equals(newLocale.getISO3Language())) {
            tts.setLanguage(newLocale);
            Log.d(TAG, "ChangeTo: " + newLocale.getISO3Language());
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "The same");
        }
    }
```

speech:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void ttsSpeak21(String text){

        String utteranceId = this.hashCode() + "";
        int result = tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, utteranceId);
        if (result == TextToSpeech.ERROR){
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't say");
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, lang + "speaking!");
        }
    }
```

free resources:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (tts != null){
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also used your subjection before using array of TextToSpeech.If you changed language immediately when needs another, it would be delayed about 5 seconds to setLanguage. That's why I used array of TextToSpeech. I want to prepare multiple TextToSpeech in advance.

Comment: In my case there are no any delayes. I'm working with multilanguges speech in my projects. I didn't mesure execatly but delay isn't more than 0.1-0.2 second beetween  to change language and start to speak a phrase.  Maybe your proplem is at a different area.